# Google Sheets Spreadsheet Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'm using Google Sheets and I have a sheet for an eCommerce store's products.
There are columns for description, features, common uses, etc. I need to take features, common uses, etc and merge them into a new cell, and format them using html, so i can easily copy and paste them into my webpage.

I want to wrap html around these echoed values.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, in case anyone would like to know:

```
=CONCATENATE("<p>",CONCATENATE(E10),"</p>")
```

Comment: If i understand you correctly, then no, there wasnt. its all relative no matter the letter (E10, E11, etc).